# NGINX: proxying and wildcard rewrite on name server

Tags: nginx

I need NGINX to proxy a certain directory to an external S3 bucket, which I'm doing like so:

```
   location ~ ^/logos/(.*)$ {
          proxy_pass           https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/logos/$1;
          proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
   }
```

I also need all other URIs to go to a wildcard CGI script.  I'm doing like this:

```
   location ~ \.cgi$  {
            include         fcgiwrap.conf;
    }
    rewrite ^ /myscript.cgi;
```

The problem is, when I put both in the same server {} declaration, they seem to be mutually exclusive. Either everything under /logos/* gets routed to the CGI script, or the CGI script gets a 404.

Comment: You may need to wrap the `rewrite` statement inside a `location / { ... }` block.

Answer (score 0):

Yep that did the trick:

```
server { 
    listen      80;
    server_name myserver.mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
    location ~ ^/logos/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass             https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/logos/$1;
        proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location ~ \.cgi$  {
        include                fcgiwrap.conf;
    }
    location / {
        rewrite                ^ /myscript.cgi;
    }
}
```